# MediaRecorder 'ondataavailable' event not firing

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-audio

Here' my complete code for displaying and live recording audio and video (*and later uploading the blob chunk into the server*):

```
$(function () {
    var handleSuccess = function(stream) {

        var player = document.querySelector("#vid-user");
        player.srcObject = stream;

        console.log("Starting media recording")
        var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
        var recordedChunks = [];
        var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
            console.log("Data available")
            if (e.data.size > 0) {
                recordedChunks.push(e.data);
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(recordedChunks));
                console.log("URL: " + url)
            }
        }

        mediaRecorder.start();
    };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
        .then(handleSuccess)
})
```

The video playback works, but the problem is that the `mediaRecorder.ondataavailable` is not triggered/called. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `start()` method takes an optional parameter called `timeslice`. Unless you specify that parameter the `dataavailable` event only fires after you call `stop()` on the `MediaRecorder`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/start

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to set

```
mediaRecorder.start(1000); // where 1000 is the interval
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution according to the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder): Use `MediaRecorder.start("time in milliseconds")` to trigger 'dataavailable' event at the specified interval AND/OR use `setTimeout(MediaRecorder.requestData(), "time in milliseconds")`. I have a jsFiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4dh0j315/4/) (not complete code, check the console messages only).

Comment: What do you mean works on jsFiddle and not on the browser? Isn't jsFiddle also is just running in the browser?

Comment: @quarks, Never mind. I edited my answer. It turned out that I had small (but significant) differences in the code loaded from my server. I fixed and got it working.